# /usr/bin/ Terminal Commands For iPhone

Tags: iphone, binary, terminal

Is there a place where I can find the directory of all `/usr/bin/` commands?  I know iPhone technically doesn't support NSTask, but this is for educational purposes so I imported a NSTask.h.  If I run `/usr/bin/cal`then it works fine, but it won't work for `/usr/bin/ls` and I cannot figure out why.

*Note: I have tried `/usr/bin/whereis ls` but that also gives me "cannot find path error"

This is my code that works:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/cal"];  //@"/usr/bin/ls" produces cannot find path error

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

label.numberOfLines=0;
label.text = string;

[label sizeToFit];

[string release];
[task release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS is basically Mac OS X, which is basically Darwin, which is basically Unix, you should just take a peak on your Mac/Darwin/Unix system.

In your Terminal (OSX) you get:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
$
```

Now, you could run this command with any directory (to which you have read+execute access) to get its contents. You can use `NSTask` for that:

```
$ /bin/ls /bin
(directory content of /bin)
...
$ /bin/ls /usr/bin
(directory content of /usr/bin)
...
```

I have no idea what this will give on a non-jailbroken iDevice.

Comment: My device is jailbroken.  I forgot to mention that.  Thanks for this!